# Remove items from QListWidget in PyQt5

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, desktop-application

I am trying to make a refresh button in pyqt5. I am building a desktop app. I wrote the code that scans particular folder and saves filenames and their paths as an array.

Array values are added to QListWidget as items

```
self.sampleChoose_list.addItems(sample_directory[0])
```

I am trying to make a function that refreshes values of the array and passes it to QListWidget.

Something like this

```
self.refreshSamples.clicked.connect(self.refreshSample)

def refreshSample(self): 
    sample_directory = []
    sample_files = []
    for (dirpath, dirnames, filenames) in walk('./Samples'):
        filenames = [f for f in filenames if not f[0] == '.']
        sample_files.extend(filenames)
        break
    the_dir = "Samples"
    paths = [os.path.abspath(os.path.join(the_dir,filename)) for filename in os.listdir(the_dir) if not filename.startswith('.')]    

    sample_directory.append(sample_files)
    sample_directory.append(paths)

    self.sampleChoose_list.addItems(sample_directory[0])
```

The problem that I struggle with is: when I push refresh button, new items get added, but the old ones are not deleted. How to remove items from QListWidget?

Comment: It seems that you are using `refreshSamples` both for the button name and the signal

Comment: updated question @Gianluca

Answer (score 25, accepted):

use `QListWidget.clear()` and it

> Removes all items and selections in the view.

for am more selective approuch you can use `QListWidget.takeItem( index )`, it

> Removes and returns the item from the given row in the list widget

---

[Official Docs: `clear()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlistwidget.html#clear)
[Official Docs: `takeItem()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlistwidget.html#takeItem)

Comment: For future coders: only the second one actually worked for me.  `list_widget.takeItem(list_widget.indexAtItem(item).row())`